# como mostrar apenas um elemento de uma lista de objetos no angular?

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

Estou percorrendo uma lista de usuarios para mostrar seus dados no html.
Na minha ultima linha, onde faço "{{ usuario.cartao | json }}" Trago uma lista de objetos que contém o cartão(ou varios cartões) de cada usuário, essa lista de objetos dos cartões trazem varios dados, como o id do cartão, o numero, nome, tipo de cartão...
Porém, eu gostaria que me retornasse, apenas o tipo de cartão(tipoCartao). Como faço para alterar esse html(ou n proprio ts) para que esse trecho do código me retorne apenas o tipo de cartão?

Trecho do código html do usuario:

```html
<tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios">
        <td> {{ usuario.id }} </td>
        <td> {{ usuario.nome }} </td>
        <td> {{ usuario.email }} </td>
        <td> {{ usuario.cartao | json }} </td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>
```

usuario.component.ts:

```js
import { UsuarioService } from './../services/usuario.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UsuarioModel } from '../usuario';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-usuario',
  templateUrl: './usuario.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./usuario.component.css']
})
export class UsuarioComponent implements OnInit {
  usuarios!: UsuarioModel[];

  constructor(private usuarioService: UsuarioService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUsuario();
  }

  private getUsuario() {
    this.usuarioService.getUsuario().subscribe(data => {
      this.usuarios = data;
    })
  }
}
```

minha interface de usuario:

```js
export interface UsuarioModel {
  id: number;
  nome: string;
  email: string;
  senha: string;
  cartao: [];
}
```

minha interface do cartão:

```js
import { UsuarioModel } from './usuario';
export interface CartaoModel {
  id: number;
  numeroCartao: number;
  nome: string;
  status: boolean;
  tipoCartao: string;
  usuario: UsuarioModel;
}
```

é assim que ta mostrando no momento:
[A intenção é só mostrar o tipo de cartao nessa telas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzOa1.png)

Sem mostrar os outros itens

Comment: O tipo do cartão é uma propriedade? Já tentou `{{ usuario.cartao.tipo }}`?

Comment: Não da. Quando faço "usuario.cartao" o cartao ja é uma lista que contém os objetos do cartão.
Só que da mesma forma que tenho o component de usuario, tenho o componente do cartão, que aí sim, tem o tipoCartao

Comment: Então talvez seja o caso de apenas pegar o índice 0 (zero) dessa coleção, sugiro colocar um exemplo de código do que vem do cartão (sem os dados reais, claro), assim facilita para entender qual é a estrutura e o problema em si.

Comment: Pronto, adicionei

Comment: Desculpa a demora, eu pensei que alguém já havia te respondido, mas acabei vendo que não, então segue uma resposta, caso ela te atenda, peço que avalie ela como positiva.

Answer (score 0):

Vendo o teu código, um usuário pode ter vários cartões, uma lista de cartão que será exibida apenas o tipo dele.

Pra resolver esse problema é necessário primeiro que tu faça um *ngFor por todos os cartões do usuário pegando apenas a propriedade `tipoCartao`, que é a que tu deseja e fazer uma interação nela da seguinte forma:

Aqui tenho o meu usuário ficticio:

```
usuario = {
    nome: 'Testerino',
    cartoes: [
      { id: 1, tipoCartao: 'credito' },
      { id: 2, tipoCartao: 'debito' },
      { id: 3, tipoCartao: 'VR' },
    ],
  };
```

E o seguinte código para listar os dados do cartão:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let cartao of usuario.cartoes"> 
    {{ cartao.tipoCartao }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

A saída será:

- credito
- debito
- VR

Neste meu exemplo eu tenho uma lista contendo os tipos de cartões do usuário.

Caso queira que todos eles apareçam em uma linha, talvez seja melhor fazer essa processo no TJ e então retorna-lo já pronto para o front, por exemplo:

```
cartoes = this.usuario.cartoes.map(x => x.tipoCartao).join().replace(',', ', ');
```

Neste caso o resultado será uma string que será apresentada da seguinte forma:

{{ cartoes }}

E a saída será:

```
credito, debito,VR
```

Fiz um [exemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krkpj7?file=src/main.ts) aqui.